# Why isn't my alarm code printing the message at the end?

Tags: python

So I'm fairly new to Python and I am trying to write a code for a timer. My code is supposed to get the hour, minute, whether it's AM or PM, and a message that they want the program to print out when their timer is done. As of now, the program asks several questions and stores them in variables, but doesn't print out the message when it is done.

I have tried looking at each part of the code and the code is fairly simple so I don't understand why this is occurring.

```
# Set up variables
hour = int(input('What should the hour be? '))

minute = input('What should the minute be? ')

ampm = input('A.M. or P.M.? ')

if (ampm == 'A.M.'):
     if (hour == 12):
    hour = 0
    else:
         hour = hour

 if (ampm == 'P.M.'):
     if (hour == 12):
         hour = hour 
     else:
         hour = hour + 12

message = input('What should the message be? ')

import datetime

current_hour = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%H')

current_minute = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%M')

alarm = True

# Set up loop
while (alarm):
    if (hour != datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%H')):
      alarm = True
    else:
        if (minute == datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%M')):
          print(message)
          alarm = False
        else: 
            alarm = True
```

It is supposed to print out the message that the user inputted. It's not doing that.

Comment: check identation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable of `hour` returns an int value and `datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%H')` returns string so your program get in the infinite loop.Change condition like

```
        if (hour != int((datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%H')))):
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Just as a clarification, you want me to put '%M', right? Because I thought that it was supposed to be '%H' for hour. Just wondering.

Comment: I added it .Just convert string to int @Dancing_Lily

Comment: And isn't it also supposed to be !=, not ==?